# Redshift SQL: how to select ltop x values for each date, without selecting duplicates for categorical column

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am trying to select the top 10 subjects by market cap for each date, without selecting duplicates of field 'subject'. I tried the following but not sure about the distinct(subject) - the ideal solution would be to select the last occurence of each individual subject occurence for each time period:

```
with temp as (
    select
        *,
        price*number_of_shares  as market_cap,
        ROW_NUMBER() Over (partition by date_trunc('day', datetime) order by market_cap desc nulls last) as row_number
    from table
)
select
    distinct(subject) as subject,
    date_trunc('day', datetime) as day,
    sum(market_cap) as market_cap
from temp 
where row_number <=10
group by subject, day
order by day desc
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.